# What is Ilford Rapid Fixer's capacity without replentishment?

Tags: printing, developing, darkroom, fixer, ilford

I've bought Ilford Rapid Fixer. I've checked the [Fact sheet](http://www.ilfordphoto.com/Webfiles/2006130218312091.pdf) and it says that capacity without replenishment for a 1+4 solution is 80 sheets of 20.3x25.4cm paper. But, what's the quantity of solution it's referring to ? I think a 1L and a 10L solution should have very a different capacity.

Answer (score 2):

The column of the table you refer to is titled "Capacity/litre of working strength fixer" so each 1L will process 80 sheets of 20.3x25.4cm paper and 10L will, therefore, process 800 sheets of 20.3x25.4cm paper, etc.